# Move values from one field to another in sql

Tags: sql

I want to transfer the values of one field, if any, to another field in the same table and replace it with zero

it is

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 |
| 3 | 0 |
| 0 | 7 |

then i want

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 3 |
| 0 | 7 |

Comment: Take the [tour] read [ask] and post a [mcve] please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below Query Replace Column B as Column A when Column B value is 0 and Column A data will be Replace with 0 in all Records

```
update TestTable set ColumnB= (case when ColumnB=0 then ColumnA else ColumnB end) ,ColumnA=0
```

Answer (score 0):

use `IIF` as follows:

```
select 
  0 as Column_A, 
  IIF(Column_B = 0, Column_A, Column_B) as Column_B 
from 
  mytable
```

Answer (score 0):

One option might be this:

**Before:**

```
SQL> select * from test;

      COLA       COLB
---------- ----------
         1          0
         3          0
         0          7
```

**Update:**

```
SQL> update test set
  2    colb = cola,
  3    cola = 0
  4  where cola <> 0;

2 rows updated.
```

**After:**

```
SQL> select * from test;

      COLA       COLB
---------- ----------
         0          1
         0          3
         0          7

SQL>
```